# DVD station and partitions disappeared, USB sticks are not recognised

Tags: hard-drive

After installing Ubuntu 11.04 my HHD partitions and DVD station disappeared, in Ubuntu 10.10 I had no issues with it. I have issues to with USB flash drives, if I connect my USB stick nothing happens and Ubuntu does not show it in the file browser.

The below screenshot it taken from my filebrowser where it usually shows the partitions and DVD station:

[image: screenshot of file browser]

Comment: 11.10 is out, are you still having this problem?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,